# Pass value to a href from Jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, json, asp.net-mvc

I have a link button in .cshtml and i need to pass Id to that from jquery function.I've tried but this is not successful.How can i do that.

### .cshtml

```
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm"><a href="/Tuition/TuitionDetails?TuitionId="+ tuitionId>More Details</a></button>
```

### Jquery

```
$("#tuitionId").text(tx.TuitionId);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you generate the whole URL from jQuery instead of just passing the ID? Like this:

```js
$("a").attr('href', `/Tuition/TuitionDetails?TuitionId=SOME_ID`);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm"><a href="#">More Details</a></button>
```

Comment: This replace all <a> attributes with this.. Is there anyway to do this is for the specific href ? because there are several <a href>'s

Comment: You can simply add an `id` attribute or a `class` to the specific `a`. And use `$("a#ID")` or `$("a.CLASS")`.

Comment: Then how do i know which specific Id bind here ?